# is it possible to make a setting enabled by default?

Tags: customization

I would like to make *Smoke Adaptive Domain* enabled by default whenever I create a *Smoke Domain*.
However, when I tried creating a smoke domain, enabling *Adaptive* (and setting the *Margin* to 2) deleting the domain, and saving the startup.blend,  it only remembered that the *Smoke Adaptive Domain* settings were expanded, rather than hidden as they are by default.

Is this possible? (it seems that it should be, as I was able to make both the *Border* setting enabled and make the preview samples value 0 by default.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer no.

Well not really, the closest thing you could get this would be...

1. Define your own operator in Python which calls the regular operator and makes some adjustments after.
2. Modify the defaults in Blender's source code *(ok, this isn't a real solution, just noting that its possible and not that hard if you build blender already)*

Both are clunky workarounds.